# Java / SSL Server Socket

Tags: java

I am writing an application that will accept LDAP queries via port 636, do some non ldap stuff, and then hand back an ldap looking response.

I'm a bit new to Java but have managed this much - I created a self signed cert, imported it into the keystore.

When attempting to make a connection I get the following error - 
main, handling exception:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: unknown_ca

Argh... I've included the debug information at the bottom.. My application does find the cert in the keystore - Thanks for any help.

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:\\openssl\\certs\\laptop.ks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "somepassword");
System.setProperty("sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation", "true");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:\\openssl\\certs\\laptop.ks");  
int port = 636;

ServerSocketFactory ssocketFactory = SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
ServerSocket ssocket;
ssocket = ssocketFactory.createServerSocket(port);

// Listen for connections
while (true)
{
    Socket socket = ssocket.accept();
    InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();

    // do stuff
socket.close();
}
```

///// DEBUG OUT when program is run

```
keyStore is : C:\openssl\certs\laptop.ks
keyStore type is : jks
keyStore provider is : 
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509
***
found key for : mylaptop
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V1
  Subject: CN=Donny Shrum, OU=HPC, O=FSU, L=Tallahassee, ST=FL, C=US
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
  modulus: <SNIP> 
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Fri Sep 30 09:55:27 EDT 2011,
           To: Sat Sep 29 09:55:27 EDT 2012]
  Issuer: CN=Donny Shrum, OU=HPC, O=FSU, L=Tallahassee, ST=FL, C=US
  SerialNumber: [    03]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature: <snip>

]
***
trustStore is: C:\openssl\certs\laptop.ks
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Donny Shrum, OU=HPC, O=FSU, L=Tallahassee, ST=FL, C=US
      Issuer:  CN=Donny Shrum, OU=HPC, O=FSU, L=Tallahassee, ST=FL, C=US
```

Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x3
  Valid from Fri Sep 30 09:55:27 EDT 2011 until Sat Sep 29 09:55:27 EDT 2012

```
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Donny Shrum, OU=HPC, O=FSU, L=Tallahassee, ST=FL, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=Donny Shrum, OU=HPC, O=FSU, L=Tallahassee, ST=FL, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0xb85a831528797e79
  Valid from Fri Sep 30 09:53:23 EDT 2011 until Sat Sep 29 09:53:23 EDT 2012

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Allow unsafe renegotiation: true
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
matching alias: mylaptop
main, called closeSocket()
Allow unsafe renegotiation: true
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
main, READ:  SSL v2, contentType = Handshake, translated length = 65
    *** ClientHello, TLSv1
Cipher Suites: <snip>

***
Cipher suite:  SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V1
  Subject: CN=Donny Shrum, OU=HPC, O=FSU, L=Tallahassee, ST=FL, C=US
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
  modulus: <snip>
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Fri Sep 30 09:55:27 EDT 2011,
               To: Sat Sep 29 09:55:27 EDT 2012]
  Issuer: CN=Donny Shrum, OU=HPC, O=FSU, L=Tallahassee, ST=FL, C=US
  SerialNumber: [    03]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
   Signature:
]
***
*** ServerHelloDone
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 662
main, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, unknown_ca
main, called closeSocket()
```

Comment: 1)I did not know that LDAP is also over SSL. Can it be? 2)Where is the code for the client? The exception means that the server is not trusted

Comment: @user384706: Yes LDAP over SSL (LDAPS) is very common.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I had a definitive answer, but the SO questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363252/received-fatal-alert-unknown-ca-while-mutual-authentication) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233206/sslhandshakeexception-unknown-ca-apns-java) seem to indicate a problem with the way the certificate was generated or imported. The first suggests regenerating without any extensions enabled. The second suggests ensuring the cert you import has the entire chain (which may not be applicable for your self-signed cert).